# Toggle two containers with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So I have a rather complex div built in HTML, interwoven with some PHP.

```
<div class="full-screen" >
    <p>
        <strong style="color: #296eaa;"> Description:</strong>
        <span data-value="1" id="description">&nbsp; <?php echo $locationDescription; ?> &nbsp; 
            <a href="#" class="pull-right edit-description" style="text-decoration:none; padding-left:10px;"><i class="fa fa-edit"> edit</i></a>
        </span>
    </p>                     
</div>
```

Presently, I create this div in two locations for two different page layouts (one for mobile, one for otherwise).
I have a click handler that I use to open an editor on the div when clicked.

```
$('.edit-description').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var contentContainer = $('#description');
    openEditor(contentContainer);
});
```

As for now, the click handler only attached to the first div on the page (which makes sense). I am sure this is a somewhat common problem, so I am just wondering what the best approach is.

I would prefer the handler to open BOTH containers on click, and all my functions (as you can see I am opening an editor on the div) to edit the same copy of the div, so if a user shrinks their screen and the screen conformation toggles, the editor remains open, and their edits are preserved.

note: Building the div in jQuery is not an option because the div is rather complex (I eliminated a lot for brevity).

Is there a way to 'clone' the div so it's behavior matches the other div?

My openEditor() function only allows one editor to be open at a time, by using .hide() on all previously open editors, but I suspect there is a way to trick this into thinking they are the same editor?

Is there a way to build one div and move it between it's two locations using a windowWidth() function?

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a jfiddle for it at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/) page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4yphp993/1/  as you can see, when you open the editor, it will only show in the full-screen page conformation.

Comment: does the elements (form in span) differ on mobile and full-screen ? Or they both can be the same instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the element on `$(window).resize()`

Add `class="toggle"` to both of the spans (make [`id` attribute **unique**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute) for each element)

```
...
<span class="toggle" data-value="1" id="description1">
...
```

Update the selector inside your click event handler:

```
$('.edit-description').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var contentContainer = $('.toggle:visible');
    openEditor(contentContainer);
});
```

Add resize event handler:

```
// cache base elements:
var mobile = $('.mobile'), fullScreen = $('.full-screen');

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(mobile.is(':visible') && $('.edit-container').length){
        $('.edit-container').appendTo(mobile);
    }else if($('.edit-container').length){
        $('.edit-container').appendTo(fullScreen);
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvohzgdc/)

---

> As for now, the click handler only attached to the first div on the page (which makes sense)

This is because your HTML is technically invalid. `id` attribute must be unique : [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute) . jQuery takes only the first element with given `id`, rest of the elements with the same `id` are not taken in.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please take a look at the update at the bottom :-)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. hadn't dealt with something like this before.